# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Services' to data type int.?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have this code

```
  select * from services where id = 2000  union select top 1   table_name,2,3,4,5,6  from information_schema.tables--
```

i need to get specified table name from my database 

i tried use this casting

 `CAST(  table_name  as nvarchar)`

aslo used this

```
convert(int,table_name)
```

but have the same error

> "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Services' to data type int."

Comment: Where are you using union? Can you post complete "relevant" code?

Comment: select * from services where id ="ID"    union select top 1   table_name,2,3,4,5,6  from information_schema.tables--

Comment: table named "services "  have six column

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete query. Also, don't concatenate strings into your sql, use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 1):

The first column of your `services` table is an int, so you can't union an nvarchar column (`information_schema.table_name`) with that.

So cast it to nvarchar:

```
select 
    CAST(ID as NVARCHAR(MAX)),
    othercolumn2,
    othercolumn3,
    othercolumn4,
    othercolumn5,
    othercolumn6
from 
    services 
where 
    id = 2000  
union 
    ...
```

Comment: i Can't Know The Name OF column That You Named CAST(ID as NVARCHAR(MAX)) :)

Comment: Yes You Can. You can just look at the schema of your `services` table.

Comment: i use to select from remote machine can't know every think from my database how can select schema with  "Union select "  with Query i have

Comment: If you execute the `select *` you'll see the column names, or you can right-click the table and select "Script Table as -> SELECT To -> New Query Editor Window" which will again show you the column names. Either way the query you're trying to execute makes very little sense.

Comment: i can't know every thing about database i have only this query 
select * from services where id = 2000  
and the name of database 
my task get all database 
i use union select to start getting information about database 
understand me :)

Comment: Nope, not at all, sorry.